# ¿Podrían ayudarme con la declaración de variables flotantes en un archivo de texto para crear una decisión?

Tags: c, float

Necesitaría pasar variables como los ingresos a flotantes ya que usando el `strlen` solo me permite en variables tipo `char` porque me esta pidiendo esto a continuación y no sabría por donde encarar sin ese `float`:

- Informar los nombres de los beneficiarios varones con ingresos mayores a $2500, indicando a que barrio pertenecen.
- La ONG necesita un listado de los beneficiarios que cumplan años en un mes determinado, indicando nombre, dirección, barrio, cantidad de hijos, estado civil y día de nacimiento.
- La ONG entrega aportes a los beneficiarios que se calcula de la siguiente forma:

  - 5 % del ingreso para ingresos > a $ 5000.
  - 8 % del ingreso para ingresos entre $ 4500 y $5000
  - 10 % del ingreso para ingresos entre $4000 y $4500.
  - 25 % del ingreso para ingresos entre $3500 y $4000.
  - 35 % del ingreso para ingresos Menores a $3500.
  - Para beneficiarios con más de 3 hijos y sean solteros o viudos se agrega además un aporte del 5% del ingreso.

¿Alguna idea o recomendación que me puedan dar?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE *fd;

struct Beneficiario {
    char Nombre [20];
    char Barrio [20];
    char Direccion [20];
    char Ingresos [20];
    char Hijos [20];
    char Documento [20];
    char Sexo [20];
    char Estado_Civil [20];

}datos;


void crear () {
    char direccion[] = "D:\\Datos\\Beneficiarios.txt";
    char rpt;

    fd = fopen(direccion,"wt"); //wt Write Text

    if (fd == NULL) {

        printf ("Error al tratar de crear el archivo");
    }

    printf ("\nCreando Datos de Beneficiarios\n");
    fprintf(fd,"\n\tBeneficiarios\n");

    do {
    fflush (stdin);
    printf ("Digite su Nombre:"); gets (datos.Nombre);
    printf ("Digite su Barrio:"); gets (datos.Barrio);
    printf ("Digite su Direccion:"); gets (datos.Direccion);
    printf ("Digite sus Ingresos:"); gets (datos.Ingresos);
    printf ("Digite su Documento:"); gets (datos.Documento);
    printf ("Digite si Tiene Hijos(s/n):"); gets (datos.Hijos);
    printf ("Digite su Sexo(m/f):"); gets (datos.Sexo);
    printf ("Digite su Estado Civil(s/c/v):"); gets (datos.Estado_Civil);


    fprintf (fd,"\nNombre: ");            //Primero el puntero, luego el dato
    fwrite (datos.Nombre,1,strlen(datos.Nombre),fd);        
    fprintf (fd,"\nBarrio: ");
    fwrite (datos.Barrio,1,strlen(datos.Barrio),fd);
    fprintf (fd,"\nDireccion: ");
    fwrite (datos.Direccion,1,strlen(datos.Direccion),fd);
    fprintf (fd,"\nIngresos: ");
    fwrite (datos.Ingresos,1,strlen(datos.Ingresos),fd);
    fprintf (fd,"\nDocumento: ");
    fwrite (datos.Documento,1,strlen(datos.Documento),fd);
    fprintf (fd,"\nHijos(s/n): ");
    fwrite (datos.Documento,1,strlen(datos.Hijos),fd);
    fprintf(fd,"\nSexo(m/f):");
    fwrite (datos.Sexo,1,strlen(datos.Sexo),fd);
    fprintf (fd,"\nEstado Civil(s/c/v)");
    fwrite (datos.Estado_Civil,1,strlen(datos.Estado_Civil),fd);
    printf ("\n\nDesea agregar mas Beneficiarios (s)");
    scanf ("%c",&rpt);  

    }while (rpt =='s'); 

}


void agregar () {

    char direccion[] = "D:\\Datos\\Beneficiarios.txt";
    char rpt;


    fd = fopen (direccion,"at"); //Add Text

    if (fd == NULL) {

        printf ("Error al tratar de agregar al archivo");

    }

    printf ("\n\t Agregando Beneficiarios");


    do {
    fflush (stdin);
    printf ("\n\nNombre:"); gets (datos.Nombre);
    printf ("\nBarrio:"); gets (datos.Barrio);
    printf ("\nDireccion:"); gets (datos.Direccion);
    printf ("\nIngresos:"); gets (datos.Ingresos);
    printf ("\nDocumento:"); gets (datos.Documento);
    printf ("\nHijos(s/n):"); gets (datos.Hijos);
    printf ("\nSexo(m/f):"); gets (datos.Sexo);
    printf ("\nEstado Civil(s/c/v)"); gets (datos.Estado_Civil);


    fprintf (fd,"\nNombre: ");
    fwrite (datos.Nombre,1,strlen(datos.Nombre),fd);    
    fprintf (fd, "Barrio: ");
    fwrite (datos.Barrio,1,strlen(datos.Nombre),fd);
    fprintf (fd,"\nDireccion: ");
    fwrite (datos.Direccion,1,strlen(datos.Direccion),fd);
    fprintf (fd,"\nIngresos: ");
    fwrite (datos.Ingresos,1,strlen(datos.Ingresos),fd);
    fprintf (fd,"\nDocumento: ");
    fwrite (datos.Documento,1,strlen(datos.Documento),fd);
    fprintf (fd,"\nHijos(s/n): ");
    fwrite (datos.Documento,1,strlen(datos.Hijos),fd);
    fprintf(fd,"\nSexo(m/f):");
    fwrite (datos.Sexo,1,strlen(datos.Sexo),fd);
    fprintf (fd,"\nEstado Civil(s/c/v)");
    fwrite (datos.Estado_Civil,1,strlen(datos.Estado_Civil),fd);
    printf ("\n\nDesea agregar mas Beneficiarios (s)");
    scanf ("%c",&rpt);


    }while (rpt == 's' );

}

void visualizar () {

  int c;
  char direccion[] = "D:\\Datos\\Beneficiarios.txt";

  fd = fopen (direccion,"r"); //Read

  if (fd == NULL) {
    printf ("Error al tratar de leer el archivo");

  }

  while ((c=fgetc(fd))!=EOF) {

    if (c == 'n'){
        printf ("\n");
    }
    else {
        putchar (c);
    }       

  } 

}



int main () {

int opc;

do {
    printf ("\n\t:MENU:.\n");
    printf ("\n1. Crear");
    printf ("\n2. Agregar mas beneficiarios");
    printf ("\n3. Visualizar beneficiarios existentes");
    printf ("\n4. Salir");

    printf ("\nOpcion:");
    scanf ("%i",&opc);


    switch (opc) {

        case 1: crear();break;

        case 2: agregar();break;

        case 3: visualizar();break;
        }

}while (opc!=4);


return 0;


}
```

Comment: Después de leer 3 veces la pregunta no me queda claro... ¿puedes o no puedes usar tipos numéricos en el ejercicio?

Comment: Al declarar las variables como float usando el strlen el compilador no me las acepta, lo que quiero saber es si hay alguna otra forma de declararlas dentro del fwrite.

Comment: Estaría bien que mostrases cómo estás intentando utilizar el tipo `float`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como norma general no tiene sentido usar cadenas de texto para almacenar secuencias numéricas por varias razones:

- Es más complicado realizar operaciones matemáticas
- Es más complicado realizar comparaciones
- Los datos ocupan más en formato texto que en formato numérico

Así pues deberías plantearte migrar aquellos registros que manejen numéricos a tipos numéricos. Tu estás hablando de usar `float` pero desde mi punto de vista es un error:

- En el código estás usando valores enteros, no decimales
- Float tiene una precisión de 6 dígitos... el resto de dígitos son basura
- No es seguro realizar comparaciones de igualdad entre dos `float` (por los dígitos basura)

Así que yo en tu lugar usaría `int`:

```
struct Beneficiario{
    char Nombre [20];
    char Barrio [20];
    char Direccion [20];
    int Ingresos;
    char Hijos [20];
    char Documento [20];
    char Sexo [20];
    char Estado_Civil [20];
};
```

Ahora bien... ¿cómo se debería realizar ahora la lectura de los datos? `scanf` es una posible solución. Una particularidad de `scanf` es que no va a eliminar el salto de línea y eso hará que el siguiente `gets` lea una cadena vacía... por no ensuciar el código tendría sentido crear una función independiente:

```
int LeerInt()
{
  int numero;
  scanf("%d",&numero);
  getchar(); // Para descartar el salto de línea

  return numero;
}
```

Con esto ya podemos actualizar la entrada de datos:

```
printf ("Digite su Nombre:"); gets (datos.Nombre);
printf ("Digite su Barrio:"); gets (datos.Barrio);
printf ("Digite su Direccion:"); gets (datos.Direccion);
printf ("Digite sus Ingresos:"); datos.Ingresos = LeerInt();
printf ("Digite su Documento:"); gets (datos.Documento);
printf ("Digite si Tiene Hijos(s/n):"); gets(datos.Hijos);
printf ("Digite su Sexo(m/f):"); gets (datos.Sexo);
printf ("Digite su Estado Civil(s/c/v):"); gets (datos.Estado_Civil);
```

Y ¿para guardar los datos en el archivo? Podemos usar `fprintf`:

```
fprintf (fd,"\nIngresos: %d",datos.Ingresos);
```

Con estos cambios realizar comparaciones es trivial:

**Filtrar beneficiarios que ganan más de 5000$**

```
struct Beneficiario beneficiarios[] = /* ... */
int numBeneficiarios = /* ... */
for( int i=0; i<numBeneficiarios; i++ )
{
  if( beneficiarios[i].Ingresos > 5000 )
  {
    // Imprimir los datos del beneficiario
  }
}
```

Y no voy a poner más código porque tu código no cumple con los requisitos exigidos en el ejercicio:

- El punto 2 no puedes hacerlo porque falta información ¿Dónde está la fecha de nacimiento?
- El punto 3 también va a ser problemático: No almacenas el número de hijos de cada beneficiario

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte tu tiempo y responder mi duda, la fecha de nacimiento no la creaba todavía porque buscaba resolver este punto para después agregar lo que faltaba . Si llego a tener otra duda lo escribo por aquí, de verdad te lo agradezco.

Comment: Si esta respuesta (o cualquier otra) soluciona tu problema, no olvides marcarla como *solución*.